# Find the solution of the initial value problem $y' = 2x / (1 + 2y)$, $y(2) = 0$ in explicit form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what I've done so far:

[image]

The answer given is $y = \sqrt{x^2 - \frac{15}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}$ so that would mean I'll have to reject $y = -\sqrt{x^2 - \frac{15}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}$ but how do I go about doing that?

Can someone give me a hint or two on how to reject $y = -\sqrt{x^2 - \frac{15}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Am I also correct to say that the solution is only defined when
x^2 - 15/4 >= 0
x^2 >= 15/4 
x  >= sqrt(15/4) or x <= -sqrt(15/4)

Since the initial condition is y(2) = 0 and the interval of validity must contain the value of x from the initial condition, the interval of validity for the solution w must be x >=  sqrt(15/4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative root does not satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: Oh ya!!! Didn't think of that haha.. Thank you so much for the help! :)